# How can i pass array to blade template through with() function in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel

Any ideas how can I access **$datainsert** array in my blade template? My project is on Laravel 8.

This is the array:

```
    $datainsert = array(
        'website' => 'john.com',
        'name' => 'John Smith'
    );
```

I'm trying with the following way but I don't know how to use that data in the blade file

```
return Redirect()->back()
            ->with('success', 'Successfully Inserted')
            ->with($datainsert);
```

I tried this in my blade file: (but it didn't worked)

```
{{ $datainsert['name'] }}
```

Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use with() with redirect()->back(), the value of the $var is not accessible through {{ $var }} but is accessible through {{ session('var') }}

Use

```
session('var')
session()->has('var')
```

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

send array in `with()`

```
return Redirect()->back()
            ->with(['success' => 'Successfully Inserted', 'datainsert' => $datainsert]);
```